# problem in Tab background

Tags: qt

In my QT application,i set a background color for main widget.And when i am running the application in KUBUNTU,background of tab which i am using in my application is the same of main window,but when i run the application in windows,the tab's background becomes white and cant display anything on tab area.

Can anyone tell me a solution??

Thank you.

Comment: Some code snippets will help determine what may be happening like the code that shows how you are setting the background color, what widgets you are using and how you are displaying things that aren't showing up when the background is white.

Comment: Ok, that's a lot of code :) It's usually better to try to paste just the relevant parts in the question using the code formatting button.

Comment: You will have to try to create a code base with the bare minimum amount of code that produces your problem. Very few people will want to try to sift through that much code. Sorry.

Comment: ok i have edited it.sorry for the long code.the edited one is at http://pastebin.com/aaALp67v

Comment: If you don't set the background color, do things work correctly?

Comment: But in Kubuntu this is working correctly then why not in windows?? and to set background color for a tab??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small problem with it. I will correct it and paste it at Pastebin soon.